# Como esperar por uma ação do usuário em um Job?

Tags: laravel, websocket, event-listener

### A Situação

Tendo uma fila de atendimento, onde sempre que um usuário entra na fila ele recebe um número de posição na fila, eu preciso solicitar a presença do primeiro da fila.

Caso o primeiro da fila não responda a solicitação em até 1 minuto (60 segundos) este deve ser removido da fila, as posições da fila são atualizadas e o processo se repete, até que o primeiro atenda a solicitação ou a fila esteja vazia, nesses casos o processo para até que seja feita uma nova solicitação para a fila.

### O que eu tenho

A fila está salva como jSon no campo `queue` na tabela `attendants` banco de dados, de acordo com o login dos usuários no formato:

```
[57,12,15,99,157] //Fila com os IDs dos usuários
```

Para processar a fila atualmente eu faço algo parecido com

```
public function offerToFirst(Collection $queue, Attendance $attendance)
{
    if ($queue->isNotEmpty()) {
        $queue->first();
        if ($attendance->current_user_id === $queue->first()) {
            return null;
        }
        sleep(60);
        $this->offerToFirst($queue, $attendance);
    }
    return null;
}
```

### O Problema

Da forma que está sendo feito hoje a requisição demora no mínimo 60 segundos ad infinitum e eu gostaria que o processamento parasse assim que uma das ações acontecesse primeiro:

- Ultrapassar 60 segundos
- O usuário que recebeu a oferta de atendimento aceitar
- O usuário que recebeu a oferta de atendimento recusar

Penso em fazer um Job que processe a fila sem precisar travar a requisição para isso. Este Job escutaria um evento disparado pelas requisições feitas pelo usuário para aceitar ou recusar a oferta, mas não sei como tratar o Job pra ouvir um evento específico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Não é possível

Um job é uma ação que acontece em segundo plano no laravel, sendo assim não existe como esperar uma ação do usuário em um job.

### Solução

Para resolver o problema, foi necessário implementar uma lógica mais complexa envolvendo novas tabelas.

Dessa forma a cada registro de oferta salvo eu tenho o quando ele foi criado e o front fica responsável por validar se o tempo foi ultrapassado ou não.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde,
Tive um problema parecido, com exceção do tempo, a solução que encontrei foi contar a quantidade de registros numa consulta e ir execução com uma chamada nova através de um trigger no jquery:

$(document).ready(function (){

var base = $(#base1).val();
var progresso = $(#progresso).val();

if($progresso < $base){
$(#buttonAtualizar).trigger('click');
}

}

Não sei se isso resolve pra você mas pode ser uma pista, se possível retorne, fiquei curioso com a forma que fez e tb não entendi mto bem a dúvida.

}

Comment: No fim das contas refatorei todo o processamento de uma forma que cada oferta era apenas apara uma pessoa e adicionei no processo várias etapas de verificação pra poder matar o processo durante a execução